# Create Count On Table That References Itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like below:

[image: Table Image]

The table lists countries and regions (states, provinces, counties, etc) within those countries. I need to generate a count of all the regions within all countries. As you can see, each region has a `ParentID` which is the `ID` of the country in which you can find the region.

As an example, California is in USA, so its parent `ID` is 1 (which is the `ID` of USA).

So, the results from the simple table above should be:

**USA: 2** and 
**Canada: 1**

I have tried the following:

1. Select all values into a table which have `ID` a 1 (for USA)
2. Select all values into a table which have `ID` a 3 (for Canada)
3. Select all values into the USA table with `Parent ID` as 1
4. Select all values into the Canada table with `Parent ID` as 3
5. Do counts on both tables

The problem with the above approach is that if a new country is added, a count will not be automatically generated.
Any ideas on making this more dynamic?

Comment: How many levels of nesting are in the table?

Comment: Just 2: Country and region

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table with itself:

```
select  t1.ID, t1.segment, count(distinct t2.ID)
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.ID = t2.parentID
where   t1.parentID is null
group by t1.ID, t1.segment
```

The where clause ensures you that only "top level" rows will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks @Stefano Zanini but this only gives the count on the top level rows. I want counts on top level + sub level

Comment: Your question states "I need to generate a count of all the regions within all countries", which makes sense since, if the levels are just Country and Region, then Region-level count will always be 1.

If you want to show Region-level count too, all you have to do is remove the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE CountriesRegions
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    parentid [int]  NULL,
    segment [nvarchar](50)  NULL) 

insert into CountriesRegions values (1,null,'usa'), (2,1, 'california'), (3, null, 'canada'), (4, 3, 'quebec'), (5, 1, 'NY')

select a.id, a.segment, count(*) as [Region Count]
from CountriesRegions a
left join CountriesRegions b
on a.id=b.parentid
where b.id is not null
group by a.id, a.segment
```

Comment: I think (1,1,'usa') should be (1,null,'usa') to match the OP's table.  However I could no submit such a small edit (fewer than 6 character change).

Comment: @Degan Thanks. I've made that change.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it makes sense to re-format the data, incase there are other sorts of queries that you want to make in addition to a count of countries and regions.

```
    CREATE TABLE #CountriesRegions
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    parentid [int]  NULL,
    segment [nvarchar](50)  NULL) 

insert into #CountriesRegions values (1,null,'usa'), (2,1, 'california'), (3, null, 'canada'), (4, 3, 'quebec'), (5, 1, 'NY')

select * from #CountriesRegions

Create table #Country
([ID] [int] NOT NULL
,[country_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)

Insert into #Country select ID, segment AS country_name from #CountriesRegions where parentid IS NULL

select * from #Country

Create table #Region
([ID] [int] NOT NULL
,[country_id] [int] NOT NULL
,[region_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)

Insert into #Region select ID, parentid AS country_ID, segment AS region_name from #CountriesRegions where parentid IS NOT NULL

select * from #Region

Select COUNT(*) As 'Num of Countries' from #Country
Select COUNT(*) As 'Num of Regions' from #Region
```